# backbone view access methods variables

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

May be a simple questions... How do I access variables in backbone.js view?

```
initialize: function() { //all init here }
render: function() {//all render here }

printFoo: function(event) {
   var printVar = this.changeFoo.changeVar  // how do I access changeVar  here???
}

changeFoo: function(event) {
  var changeVar = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
}
```

how do I access changeVar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

Reason: `changeVar` is a private member of `changeFoo`.

You could *promote* `changeVar` to become a member of the outer object. In which case, `changeVar` becomes accessible to `initialize`, `render`, `printFoo` and `changeFoo`.

```
function ConstructorFunctionName(){
    var changeVar = 'foo';
    /*this.changeVar = 'foo'; // this can also be used */

    this.initialize = function() { //all init here };
    this.render = function() { //all render here };

    this.printFoo = function(event) {
       var printVar = changeVar;
    };

    this.changeFoo = function(event) {
      this.changeVar = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Njwdx/

Comment: how this would look like?  just just make changeVar global (no var declaration) ?

Comment: it'd require you to change the way the "object" is constructed, updating answer now ...

Comment: thanks. since everything is wrapped in Backbone.View.extend({}) I just did this:  changeFoo: function(event) { this.changeVar = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id'); }     and now I can acces changeVar