# Accessing method variables in Backbone views (parse views)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

How can I access object "context" in Parse.find function globally? I am getting an error "Uncaught reference error: context not defined". I am new to backbone.js. I have seen couple of posts regarding scoping of backbone views. But they didn't help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    var MessageView = Parse.View.extend({

    el: "#post",

    context:"",

    tagName:  "li",

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.render();
        console.log('Message View Initialized');    
    },
    render: function(res) {
      //var context;  

      // declaring it here as a global variable doesn't help

      var query = new Parse.Query(Message);
  query.find({
    success:function(results){

        for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
            results[i].from=results[i].attributes.from;
            results[i].message=results[i].attributes.messageBody;
            message.set("from",results[i].from);
            message.set("message",results[i].message);
        }

   context={from:message.attributes.from,message:message.attributes.message};

   //I want this object to be accessed anywhere in the render function

    },
    error:function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
  });
  var source=$("#messageTmpl").html();
  var messageTemplate = Handlebars.compile(source);

  // I need to access context object in parse.find({}) here
  // context variable with values "from" and "messageBody"

     var html = messageTemplate(context);
  console.log(context);
  this.$el.html(html);   
},
});
```

I found this question very similar to mine. 
[question][backbone view access methods variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391512/backbone-view-access-methods-variables)

Answer (score 0):

declare it as a view property?

var MessageView = Parse.View.extend({

```
el: "#post",

context:"",

tagName:  "li",

query: new Parse.Query(Message),

initialize: function() {
    ...
},
render: function(res) {
    ...
```

Comment: I have already declared it as a view property, but how do I pass the value to that view property ? I want to pass the context object to the  context view property. Right now I have put an empty string.

Comment: you can declare as the view property and then initialize later eg from `initialize()`?

Comment: How do I set context view property with context object? I am new to backbone.

Comment: `self.query = new Parse.Query(Message)` or `this.query = new Parse.Query(Message)`?